# How to create a public repository on Github but hide certain aspects

Tags: xcode, github

How can I create an Xcode project and push it to a GitHub repository that is public BUT hides keys.

For example if I have Firebase keys and I push my project to GitHub can't anybody see them and then do whatever they please with my data?

Comment: *"can't anybody see them and then do whatever they please"* - yes, that's why you don't check in keys. You can't make part of a GH repo private, as far as I'm aware, but you *can* `.gitignore` the files with secrets in.

Comment: @jonrsharpe what do you mean by "check in" ...some of the keys are in things like the .plist and others are in the build settings...if I don't push those then the project is kind of ruined if I ever needed to download it ....so I guess .gitignore is the best option?

Comment: It's not ruined, you just need to transfer the keys by some other means than a public repo. See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/30803506/3001761